# how i can change this code to functional component in react

Tags: reactjs

Here how i can change this code to functional component. If i try to change this to functional component in console data is keep on printing. how i can solve that error. Kindly provide solution for this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getUsers } from "../actions/exampleAction";

function Users (props) {
    props.getUsers();
    const { users } = props.users;
        console.log(props.users);

        return (
            <div>
                {users.length &&
                    users.map((user) => {
                        return (
                            <React.Fragment key={user.id}>
                                <h6> {user.first_name} </h6>
                                <p> {user.last_name} </p>
                                <p> {user.email}</p>
                                <p>
                                    <img key={user.avatar} src={user.avatar} alt="avatar" />
                                </p>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        );
                    })}
            </div>
        );
    }


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ users: state.users });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUsers })(Users);
```

Comment: Include what you have tried in the functional component.

Comment: i have included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, at the during the initial rendering of the component, `props.getUsers()` is called, when it is changed, again the props changes and component is rendered.

That's why you get multiple console logs.

You can read about *side effects* and *using hooks* on Functional Components [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```jsx
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getUsers } from "../actions/exampleAction";

function Users(props) {
  const { users } = props.users;

  useEffect(() => {
    props.getUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {users.length &&
        users.map((user) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={user.id}>
              <h6> {user.first_name} </h6>
              <p> {user.last_name} </p>
              <p> {user.email}</p>
              <p>
                <img key={user.avatar} src={user.avatar} alt="avatar" />
              </p>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ users: state.users });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUsers })(Users);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use hook available from "`react-redux`" instead of `mapStateToProps` or `mapDispatchToProps` as given below

And you don't need to pass `getUsers` as props because you already import it at the top so you can directly use it without props.

So go through following code and improve your coding standard

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { getUsers } from "../actions/exampleAction";

function Users(props) {

     const users = useSelector(state => state.users);
     useEffect(() => {
         getUsers();
     }, []);

    if(!users.length) return null;

    const userData = users.map((user) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={user.id}>
          <h6> {user.first_name} </h6>
          <p> {user.last_name} </p>
          <p> {user.email}</p>
          <p>
            <img key={user.avatar} src={user.avatar} alt="avatar" />
          </p>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });
    
    return (
       <div>
          {userData}
       </div>
    );
}

export default Users;
```

Comment: this one is not working